# can't find developers command prompt for visual studio 2013 Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use the Visual Studio Developers Command prompt, but I can't find it. I have Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Server 2012. I have tried searching for 'Developer command prompt' and various shorter versions of that. The only search that gives me something is when I search 'VS2012 command prompt' which gives me the following:
- VS2012 ARM Cross Tools command prompt 
- VS 2012 x86 Native Tools Command prompt
- VS 2012 x64 Native Tools Command prompt

I don't think those are what I'm looking for. I have Visual Studio so I should have it installed. How can I find it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS 2013, all the Developer Command Prompts are in a "Visual Studio Tools" subfolder in the start menu created by VS 2013. Typically you'll find them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`. For whatever reason, those don't show up in desktop search.

For VS 2015, they put them back where desktop search can find them.